# The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

Tags: mysql

I m getting the error - The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair

while repairing the tables through command -  mysqlcheck -u root -p --repair "database"

It displays error for 4 tables only out of 106 tables , for rest of the tables it displays OK.

Pls help if there is any work around.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Myisam` engine supports this functionality and I believe these 4 tables are not myisam type.

as manual says :

> The MyISAM storage engine supports all
>   four maintenance operations, so
>   mysqlcheck can be used to perform any
>   of them on MyISAM tables. Other
>   storage engines do not necessarily
>   support all operations. In such cases,
>   an error message is displayed. For
>   example, if test.t is a MEMORY table,
>   an attempt to check it produces this
>   result:

For further Detail see [myisamcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlcheck.html)

You can change the engine of tables if they fit for myisam

Answer (score 1):

You cannot repair an InnoDB type table, If you want to repair them you’ll have to change the table engine from InnoDB to MyIsam.

To Do this, follow these simple steps

- Open your phpmyadmin
- Select  the database you want to repair.
- Look for the table(s) with InnoDB type storage engine and note down their names.
- Now you need to perform an SQL command by clicking on the SQL tab that appears on the top section of that page.
- Now use the command given below

  `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE=MyISAM;`
- Replace the table_name with the name of the table you want to change from InnoDB to MyISAM.

Note: You will have to do the table change one by one.  For each time, chose one table and change its engine and so on.

Source: [Error in mysql repair-The storage engine for the table doesn’t support repair while repairing | cPanelWhm.org](http://cpanelwhm.org/mysql-database/error-in-mysql-repair-the-storage-engine-for-the-table-doesnt-support-repair/158)